# g++ equivalent compiler flags to VC++ compiler Flags

Tags: visual-c++, gcc, opencv, g++, mingw

I have the below lines in one of the stasm examples make file. But it looks like these options are for VC++. I want to compile the same in g++ ( mingw ) compiler. So what are the equivalent flags in g++ which are equivalent to the below mentioned compiler flags.

Please provide me any links or your valuable suggestions.
Thanks..

> cl -nologo -O2 -W3 -MT -EHsc -DWIN32 stasm_opencv_example.cpp
>   -I%OPENCV_HOME%\include\opencv %OPENCV_HOME%\lib\cv210.lib %OPENCV_HOME%\lib\cxcore210.lib %OPENCV_HOME%\lib\highgui210.lib
>   ..\data\stasm_dll.lib

Comment: would be helpful you you gave an explanation of the flags you use in VC++, which one are important, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know MINGW, but I do use -on Linux- (and contribute to) GCC so you might try

```
 g++ -O3 -Wall -DWIN32 -I$OPENCV_HOME/include/opencv \
    -L$OPENCV_HOME/lib -lcv210 -lcxcore201 -lhighgui20 ../data/stasm_dll.lib
```